# Ms Access frontend, PostgreSQL backend efficient INSERT INTO ... RETURNING ... statement

Tags: ms-access, postgresql, vba

HI,

I'm using MS Access as a frontend to PostgreSQL database.
And I have run into dead end:

How would I get return value of passthrough SQL INSERT statement?

I tried something like this:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO someTable (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2') RETURNING col0"
'Create passtrhough query dynamically (another function)
CreateSPT ("some_temp_query", strSQL)
idvalue = DLookup("col0", "some_temp_query")
```

Apparenty this way INSERT statement will be called 2 times :)
Does anybody know what is the correct way? I have run out of ideas

Edit: I'm using latest psqlODBC drivers

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a saved pass-though query, then you can modify the sql on the fly, and return values that way. The following code runs without you even having to declare any variables.

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPassReturn")
   .SQL = "INSERT INTO someTable (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2') RETURNING col0"
   Debug.Print .OpenRecordset()(0)
End With
```

I suppose you could declare a reocrdset to receive the return value, and go:

```
Dim rstReturn  As DAO.Recordset

With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPassReturn")
   .SQL = "INSERT INTO someTable (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2') RETURNING col0"
   Set rstReturn = .OpenRecordset
End With

Debug.Print rstReturn(0)
```

So, you can just pass the sql, and the values returned will appear as a standard reocrdset. So, the first example should run fine and note how I not even declared one varialbe to make this work. You as mentioned simply need a saved pass-though query.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that function below does the trick... Not sure about performance though :)

```
'Insert-SQL passthroug
'Pass here all the insert statements
Function ISPT(SQLString)
Dim strODBCString As String
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim result As Long

    strODBCString = _
      "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};DATABASE=" & settings_getDBName() & _
      ";SERVER=" & settings_getServerAddress & _
      ";PORT=" & settings_getServerPort & _
      settings_getConnStrParams

      cn.Open strODBCString

      rs.Open SQLString, cn


      'return value
      result = rs.Fields(0).Value



    'Cleanup
    If rs.state <> adStateClosed Then rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    If cn.state <> adStateClosed Then cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

    ISPT = result

End Function
```